# How to I correctly implement this batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to correctly inplement a batch file where a user can input values that fill into this script to pull from a different apps cmd file and pull image files from the server.

https://support.imago.live/hc/en-us/articles/360000870052-Downloading-Images-from-Imago

Generic command from Imago:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Imago\imago-tools\imago-cmd.exe" export --user ImagoDemo1 --password ImagoDemo1 "Imago Demo" "Drilling Hard Rock" "AA222" "C:\Scratch"
```

This is my command:

```
@ECHO off

SET /p un="UserName: "
SET /p pw="Password: "
SET /p Region="Enter Region: "
SET /p projname="Project Name: "
SET /p filter="What filter on hole: "
SET /p destination="Destination Source: C:\Temp\"
SET "ImTool=C:\Program Files (x86)\Imago\imago-tools\imago-cmd.exe"

"%ImTool%" export -- user "%un%" -- password "%pw%" "%Region%" "%projname%" "%filter%" "C:\Temp\%Destination%"
```

If I fill in the generic command and it interprets my user input and runs the command using the values I want to send to it.

I want these transfers of information:

- `un` as `"user"`
- `pw` as `"password"`
- `region` as `"Imago Demo"`
- `projname` as `"Drilling Hard Rock"`
- `filter` as `"AA222"`
- `destination` as `"C:\Scratch"`

[CODE pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kll4D.png)

Comment: That looks reasonable. What's it doing now that isn't working?

Comment: Should it not be `--user` and `--password`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work because you have splited `--` and switch name:

```
@ECHO off 
SET /p un="UserName: " 
SET /p pw="Password: " 
SET /p Region="Enter Region: " 
SET /p projname="Project Name: " 
SET /p filter="What filter on hole: " 
SET /p destination="Destination Source: C:\Temp\" 
SET "ImTool=C:\Program Files (x86)\Imago\imago-tools\imago-cmd.exe" 
"%ImTool%" export --user "%un%" --password "%pw%" "%Region%" "%projname%" "%filter%" "C:\Temp\%Destination%"
```